# Why hikaricp gives me Method not found: setUrl at startup?

Tags: hibernate, maven, jetty, hikaricp

I am developing a GWT app without Maven nor Spring, but I want to use HikariCP as my connection pool so I downloaded HikariCP-2.2.4.jar from Maven's Central Repository along with pgjdbc-ng-0.3-complete.jar for my postgresql driver; finally I have updated my hibernate libraries from 4.1 to 4.3.

I am using the following HikariCP Properties on my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">user</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">pass</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</property>
```

Now, when i start the application it gives me the next Exception:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setUrl
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider.configure(HikariConnectionProvider.java:84)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
>       at org.persistencias.HibernateSessionFactory.(HibernateSessionFactory.java:43)
>       at org.persistencias.BaseHibernateDAO.getSession(BaseHibernateDAO.java:14)
>
> .
>   .
>   .
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setUrl
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setProperty(PropertyBeanSetter.java:129)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyBeanSetter.java:58)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PoolUtilities.initializeDataSource(PoolUtilities.java:134)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:142)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:109)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:78)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider.configure(HikariConnectionProvider.java:80)
>       ... 49 more
>   Caused by: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setUrl
>       at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.(PropertyDescriptor.java:110)
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setProperty(PropertyBeanSetter.java:120)
>       ... 55 more

I have searched here on stackoverflow and googled but have not found anything so far, can anyone give me a hint with this?

Thank you!

Comment: First, assuming this is the correct config you posted, your property is wrong `hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassNam` should have a 'e' added to the end. Next you don't need the URL afaik. I would also suggest using Spring to configure the datasource and the hibernate session factory makes your life easier.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, thanks for your suggestion but I think it would need even more time for start using Spring.

Comment: Why would it take more time (according to the tags you use Spring so why would it be harder?).

Comment: Mmm because I never used it and I dont know how easy is to adapt it to my existing project. I used that tag because of "java.beans.IntrospectionException" and everywhere people talk about Spring (,sorry for the misinformation). So I want to have it working without Spring.

Comment: Regardless of that, there is no `url` property on the `PGDataSource` and with HikariCP it is even discouraged to use a URL. Simply set the `host` and `database` property instead.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem but now I am getting another error: "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization" ... Caused by: com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGSQLSimpleException: Connection Error: password authentication failed for user "postgres". Dont know if you can help me with this? Sorry if I am abusing hehe and thanks for your time and your edit ;)

Comment: I would say the username/password is wrong...

Comment: Jajaja no, obviously i made sure the password was right but in the end it was because I still had libraries of my previous hibernate version not in my .classpath but in my WEB-INF/lib/ directory, so I deleted them and everything went fine. Thank you M. Deinum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pgjdbc-ng PGDataSource does not have a setter for a url property.  The URL is "composed" internally by pgjdbc-ng.  You need to setup the DataSource using the individual properties:

`hibernate.hikari.dataSource.host=localhost
hibernate.hikari.dataSource.port=5432
hibernate.hikari.dataSource.database=db`

Comment: Thank you so much, where did you find this info? or where can i find it? Because now I have a new Error "Fail-fast during pool initialization" ... com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGSQLSimpleException: Connection Error: password authentication failed for user "postgres", do you have any idea? Thanks